# Django IntegrityError with UniqueConstraint when switching field value between two entries

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to write a Model in Django to add emails with specific attributes/options to a contact.

As there should only be one billing mail per contact, I added a UniqueConstraint.
Adding, updating and deleting entries works fine.

However when I want to change which email address is the billing email address I get an error, when I try to just switch the checkboxes between the two entries (disable one and enable the other at the same time/in one go).

As a workaround I can first disable the checkbox and save, then enable the other one and save again.

For example in this picture I want to make `billing@abc.com` my billing email, which currently is `admin@abc.com`.

[image]

Now when I change the checkboxes as described I get the following error:

```
Django Version: 4.2.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: account_email.contact_id, account_email.is_billing_email
```

The model used for this does look like this:

```py
class Email(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contact_emails")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, db_index=True, null=False, blank=False)
    is_contact_email = models.BooleanField(_("contact email"), default=True)
    is_billing_email = models.BooleanField(_("billing email"), default=False)
    is_subscribed_to_status_notifications = models.BooleanField(_("status notifications"), default=True)
    is_subscribed_to_newsletter = models.BooleanField(_("newsletter"), default=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["contact", "email"],
                name="contact_and_email_unqiue"
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["contact", "is_billing_email"],
                name="one_billing_email_per_contact",
                condition=models.Q(is_billing_email=True)
            )
        ]
```

What exactly is causing this error and how can I fix it?

I tried to switch from `unique_together` to `models.UniqueConstraint`, as UniqueConstraint is better supported. But I couldn't fix the issue this way.

Comment: This is not (much) a modeling issue, but the form itself that saves items one-by-one (and checks constraints one-by-one), whereas for a formset it should do that in bulk.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, how do you use those formsets in Inline ModelAdmins?